# Where am i doing wrong?

Tags: perl

I want to go in the loop only if an input is given between 1 to 5 else it should ask for "Enter valid option: "

Here is what I have tried

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Switch;


print qq/\tMENU\n 1.BACKUP\n 2.RESTORE\n 3.TABLESPACES\n 4.BUFFERPOOLS\n 5.EXIT\n/;
print "Enter Your Choice : ";

while(<STDIN>){
        chomp;
        if (1..5){
        print qq/wright\n/;
        } else {
        print qq/wrong\n/;

        }
}
```

I'm on my half way and I have tried to give a check whether its working or not , but it not ....even if I give 6 or 7 .... as input its giving write , I mean its going in if loop instead of else........help is appreciated ........

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: i mean , even if i give 6 or 7 .... as input its giving write , i mean its going in if loop instead of else

Comment: hmm not when I run it

Comment: Why do you need to use this check if you intend to use `Switch`, I wonder? These cases (when input is incorrect) will be safely captured by `default` clause.

Comment: use if (/[1-5]/) instead of if (1..5) ,,, this one is working for me instead ....... don't know why

Comment: I do not have `Switch` installed so I commented that line out before I ran the OP's script.  Maybe the script would work as expected if `use Switch;` is commented out.

Comment: Ya ya ,, i'm new to perl and i'm quite comfortable with shell scripting , just trying to try out different ways of approach ...so got stuck at this point ...

Comment: @Red Cricket I have commented use switch , but still its not working for me ....

Comment: It is because `(1..5)` returns true.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that `1..5` in scalar context is the flip-flop version of the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

> Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the
>   right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false
>   again.

`1` is always true, so your if statement is always true the first time through.  `5` is also always true, so the if statement becomes false the second time through and stays false thereafter.  Note that your input variable is never involved in any of this.

You can use a regex, but if you do you need to anchor it:

```
if (/^[1-5]$/)
```

The anchors ensure that the *whole string* is a single character between 1 and 5.  If you just use `if (/[1-5]/)`, that matches anything that *contains* a digit 1-5, so `1200` and `foo5` would count as valid.

However, presumably you are going to do five different things based on what the user entered.  Therefore, you probably shouldn't use a regex at all, but just check for each condition:

```
 if    ($_ == 1) { do something         }
 elsif ($_ == 2) { do something else    }
 elsif ($_ == 3) { do something else    }
 elsif ($_ == 4) { do something else    }
 elsif ($_ == 5) { do something else    }
 else            { handle invalid input }
```

You can use different syntax to accomplish the same thing with the [`Switch` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html) (which you are including but not actually using in your code):

```
switch ($_) {
case 1      { print "number 1" }
case 2      { print "number 2" }
case 3      { print "number 3" }
case 4      { print "number 4" }
case 5      { print "number 5" }
else        { print "invalid"  }
}
```

Yet another possibility (as Raina77ow suggested) is using the [smartmatch operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator).  It has a variety of uses, including checking for existence of an element in an array:

```
my @valid_input = (1..5); #Range operator in list context generates an array.
if ($_ ~~ @valid_input) { print "Input was a number between 1 and 5"; }
```

You can shorten that code by using an anonymous array reference (`[ ]`).

```
if ($_ ~~ [1..5]) { print "Input was a number between 1 and 5"; }
```

Comment: +1, as it's the only answer here that actually mentions the difference between using regex and using range check. IMO, this answer can be improved by mentioning smart match (`if ($_ ~~ [1..5])`), but that's your choice to be made. )

Comment: First, you _usually_ don't use regex to do `in_array` job. Yes, it can be done in this particular case (as we work with strings), but without understanding why it's working, it's actually useless as an SO answer. Second, I always thought of smart matching arrays/arrayrefs by scalars as a very straight-forward - and natural - thing. Perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: @raina77ow, sorry, from glancing at your suggestion I thought you meant `$_ ~~ /[1-5]/` (which is valid, but pointless).  I agree that smartmatch is useful for checking if something is in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this loop instead:

```
my $input;
do {
  print "Enter valid option: ";
  chomp ($input = <STDIN>);
} while ($input < 1 && $input > 5);
```

Comment: Ya this kind of is working , just wanted to try out with range comparisons and so...........Thanks for your reply

Comment: @mViswa It's just an alternative I suppose.

Comment: Ya ya ,, i'm new to Perl and i'm quite comfortable with shell scripting , just trying to try out different ways of approach ...so got stuck at this point ...

Answer (score 0):

use `if (/^[1-5]$/)` instead of `if (1..5)`

Comment: its working but whats wrong with i have declared .... I have surfed perldoc and i have found the same usage as i have done in it

Comment: You can use `..` to generate an array in list context, such as `for (1..5)` but in `if (1..5)` it's rather a scalar context, where `..` returns a boolean value which is always true.

Comment: O sry, I should have added the anchor. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
if ($_ =~ /^[1-5]$/)
```

or

```
if (/^[1-5]$/)
```